# Google script stop loop after first match

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have script that compare dates in column with today date and sending email. Problem is that it send lots email for each compared cell.

Here is my code

```
function sendEmailAlert3() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID");
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var sheetname = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getName();
var fValues = sheet.getRange('F2:F20').getValues();
var day = 24*3600*1000
var today = parseInt((new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))/day);
var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
var Toemail = 'mail@gmail.com';
var subject = 'Theme - ' + ss.getName();
var body = 'Edited - ' + sheetname + '\nBy - ' + user +
    '\nCheck - ' + ss.getUrl();
var NoEditSubject = 'No ' + ss.getName() + '!';
var NoEditBody = 'No - ' + sheetname +  ss.getUrl();
for (var i = 0; i < fValues.length; i++) {
    var dataday = parseInt(fValues[i][0].getTime()/day)
    Logger.log(dataday+' = '+today)
    if (dataday <= today-5) {MailApp.sendEmail(Toemail,subject, body);}
    else {MailApp.sendEmail(Toemail,NoEditSubject, NoEditBody);}  
    }
}
```

I need add one more condition smth like `next cell == false`.

`If (dataday <= today-5 || next cell == false)` - for first match of this condition need email once and stop the loop

`Else if (dataday <= today-5 || next cell == true)` - for first match of this condition need email once and stop the loop

`else` - do nothing

**EDIT** after all answer my code look like that (bottom part):

```
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2,7,2,1);
var data = dataRange.getValues();
for (i = 0; i < fValues.length; i++) {
  var dataday = parseInt(fValues[i][0].getTime()/day)
  for (k = 0; k < data.length; k++) {
    Logger.log(dataday)
    if (dataday <= today+5 && data[k][0] == "false") 
    {MailApp.sendEmail(Toemail,subject, body);
          }
  }
}
```

But it still not working.
I'll try to specify what's problem. 
[image]

Condition is (dataday <= today+5 && data[k][0] == "false"). In this case script must send only one email. Because both condition are true only for first row. But it send two email. I don't know what's the problem.

Comment: What is next cell?

Comment: I mean my range is F2:F20, "next cell" it's cell on next column G.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to implement a return statement inside the if statement - this will make the loop stop after the first email will be sent. Like this:

```
 if (dataday <= today-5) {
      MailApp.sendEmail(Toemail,subject, body); 
      return;
    }
    else {MailApp.sendEmail(Toemail,NoEditSubject, NoEditBody);}
```

For the second part of your question: you can exit nested loops if you name them and then exit with "break" specifying which loop you want to exit, as explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label):

```
var i, j;

loop1:
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {      //The first for statement is labeled "loop1"
   loop2:
   for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {   //The second for statement is labeled "loop2"
      if (i === 1 && j === 1) {
         break loop1;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's work. What about second condition? I tried like that 

`for (var i = 0; i < fValues.length; i++) {
  var dataday = parseInt(fValues[i][0].getTime()/day)
  for (var j = 0; j < gValues.length; j++) {
    var datacheck = parseInt(gValues[j][0])
    Logger.log(dataday+' = '+today)
    if (dataday <= today+5 && datacheck == false) {MailApp.sendEmail(Toemail,subject, body);
                            return;}
    else {MailApp.sendEmail(Toemail,NoEditSubject, NoEditBody);
         return;}  
    }
}`

Comment: It works for me. Did you put "return;" into a new line after "MailApp.sendEmail(Toemail,NoEditSubject, NoEditBody);"?

Comment: Yes, return is work. I'm talking about second condition. It's don't work.

Comment: Oh, I see, you edited your question and have a nested loop. I will update my answer.

Comment: hey, i tried "return". It not work in my case, because it stop after checking first row. But i need to check all range. I edited my code. Can you look it?

Comment: As I mentioned in my updated answer - if you a nested loop, you need to use break instead of return and specify that you want to break from the outer loop (loop 1 in the example).